# GS: Make recursive script

Tags: recursion, ssh, ghostscript

Im using this script to resize some scaned pdf files that users upload to FTP. What i need is to reduce the size of pdf, to reduce the time to process them (upload to s3, etc).

The script:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf
```

So my question is: How can i make this recursive? I need all files in the folder to be reduced. If this can overwrite the original file, then is perfect.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't overwrite the original file simply by using Ghostscript. You can, of course, using a shell script but I would suggest you think very carefully before doing so. The operation Ghostscript is performing is highly complex, and if anything goes wrong, you will overwrite the original meaning you will have lost something.

Comment: @KenS Thanks for the comment. I did what the answer above says, and i overwritte all files with empty pdf file. So now i need to upload all files again. Any idea of how can i accomplish this?

Comment: I'm no expert in shell scripting, but I would suggest that writing the new files to a new directory would be the simplest option. Eg set -sOutputFile=./reduced/$f or something similar. The reason you ended up with empty files is because as soon as GS started up it opened (for write) the output file. Since that was the input file, it immediately truncated it, before GS had read the contents. As I said, you can't do it with GS, and I think you should be careful with a shell script too in case errors occur.

Comment: @KenS That should be the correct answer. Thanks Ken, now i get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script is not a script. It is a command line.

You could write a shell script to iterate over all *.pdf files in the folder, and then call `gs ...` for each.

Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.pdf
do
    gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=processed/$f $f
done
```

Comment: Thnks for the answer! Is there any way i can run this in command line and not make .bash ?

Comment: Copy pasted this answer, and all my files gets overwritte with empty pdf

Comment: Hi! Can you change your example with the output=/processed/$f ? So nobody else get data lost ? Thanks!