# How to convert all folder pdfs to png using ghostscript

Tags: ghostscript

i want to convert all pdfs of folder to png images,like if i have two pdfs in folder name test1.pdf and test2.pdf with two pages,then it should generate test1-1.png ,test1-2.png,test2-1.png,test2-2.png.
I am using this command line ,what should i place instead of '#-%d.png'?

gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=png16m -sOutputFile="/var/www/pdf_png/pdfs/#-%d.png" /var/www/pdf_png/pdfs/*.pdf

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it using Ghostscript alone, you need to write a shell script to invoke Ghostscript on each source file.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42557785/gs-make-recursive-script) has a script in it that you may be able to adapt for your purposes

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir,i tried this                                                                  for i in $(find "C:/pdfthumbs/input/test_pdf/" -name "*.pdf"); do e="$(basename $i '.pdf')-%d.png";gswin -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=png16m -sOutputFile="C:/pdfthumbs/input/test_images/"$e $i; done                          And it works in ubuntu,but same thing not working with 'win64'.

Comment: Well that's because Windows command shell is not bash, so a bash script isn't going to work. I pointed you at that question because you seemed to be using Linux. If you search the site under the Ghostscript tag you will find similar solutions for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type f -iname "*.pdf" -exec sh -c 'gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pngalpha -r300 -sOutputFile=$1.png $1' x {} \;
```

Note: This will still output `FILENAME.pdf.png`, but hey ... it's a one liner ...

### Explanation

- `find` command finds all `pdf` files and passes them to `sh` via `-exec`
- the `{}` represents the file name, but in order to be used twice in the command it has to be passed with the `sh -c` trick as a positional argument
- in case you are wondering the character `x` is passed as the `$0` argument because convetionally `$0` is the shellname
- `\;` is the character used to signal the end of the command